# What does this regex expression mean?

Tags: python, regex

I am very weak at regular expressions, now I'm debugging some code, the code is searching strings with an expression like:

```
r"coding[:=]\s*([-\w.]+)"
```

What kind of string does it search for?

To me, it seems to match something like:

```
coding= xxxxx
```

but I don't know the exact meaning of the mystery character. Can anyone explain in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's break this down:

- `coding`: literal text match, only the word "coding" will do
- `[:=]`: character group, either a colon ":" or an equals sign "=" matches
- `\s*`: 0 or more whitespace characters; spaces and tabs, but could match newlines too if so configured.
- `(..)`: a matching group, the contents will be available as a match group for further processing.
- `[-\w.]+`: one or more characters in the group, matching a dash "-", a dot "." or any word character; `\w` is a character class usually matching the letters 'a' through 'z' (upper and lowercase), numbers '0' up to '9' and the underscore "_".

If you switch on unicode support (on by default in Python 3) the `\w` class captures a lot more though. Any character classified as an alphanumeric in the Unicode database would match.

Examples of matches:

- "coding=foobar320_42spam_eggs", group would be `foobar320_42spam_eggs`
- "coding: something-or-other", group would be `something-or-other`
- "coding:       whatever.42", group would be `whatever.42`

Answer (score 2):

It will match the following:

`coding` + one of `:` or `=` + zero or more spaces (`\s` = space, tab, any whitespace char) + some text, that may also contain `.` and `-`.

Answer (score 1):

Sample Expressions for your Regular Expression http://rubular.com/r/cqE6HTD8Vb